# Failed to pull oracle standard DB image from container-registry.oracle.com

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-machine, docker-daemon

I have installed Docker in my Windows 11 home edition and tried to pull Oracle standard DB image from container-registry.oracle.com. However i got the following error.

## docker login container-registry.oracle.com

Username (XXXX):

Password:

Error response from daemon: Get "https://container-registry.oracle.com/v2/": dialing container-registry.oracle.com:443 no HTTPS proxy: resolving host container-registry.oracle.com: lookup container-registry.oracle.com: no such host.

Any idea on how to resolve this error.

PS : I'm using ubuntu 18.04 as WSL2. System has 8 gb ram, 512 gb SSD and has AMD ryzen 5 series as chip.

Have anyone any suggestions how to solve, or at least how to debug this problem?

Comment: nc -vz container-registry.oracle.com 443
Connection to container-registry.oracle.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!

Comment: I couldn't understand this answer. could you please elaborate it ? Do u want me to type the above command in windows powershell ? If yes, this needs to be typed before  
 **docker login container-registry.oracle.com** command ?

Comment: From the manual: "The nc (or netcat) utility is used for just about anything under the sun involving TCP or UDP". "nc -vz container-registry.oracle.com 443" will test the connectivity to host and port. You need a successful connection before you can login to the registry.

Comment: It looks like the host name `container-registry.oracle.com` isn't being resolved, which suggests a problem with your DNS configuration. You might need to search for how to check and configure that properly. That isn't a topic covered by this site though - maybe start on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can open cmd as run as admin and then try again the same command. It worked for me.

```
docker login container-registry.oracle.com
```